# Show City/Road/State/Country Label in satellite viewGoogle Map V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello I am using Google Maps API v2 for displaying the maps in android. Now I want to display Place labels in the satellite view. like SATUN , PERLIS etc... Though In the normal map view it is showing. Anybody know how to achieve that in satellite view?

[image: Satellite Image]  [image: Simple Map]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

This code will change the map type to hybrid which have both satellite and place name...

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the names show up only on a higher zoomlevel in this mode than in the default mode.